# Apache on Mac: vhost looks for wrong directory (other than DocumentRoot)

Tags: macos, apache-http-server, localhost, virtual-host

I just un-installed XAMPP and decided to take into use the Apache included within OS X. After a lot of fiddling around I've gotten it to somewhat work, but not quite.

I use VirtualHostX for managing vhosts to my local projects. When I add a vhost (e.g. `project.dev` -> `htdocs/Project`) using the app, that vhost will work properly.

However, when I try to access `localhost`, things get weird. Let's say I navigate to `localhost/foo` on my browser. It gives 404, and this can be found in the error-logs:

> [error] [client 127.0.0.1] File does not exist: /path/to/htdocs/Project/foo

So, basically it seems that the first vhost I have set up defines the folder where `localhost/*` tries to look for files.

Any ideas? It is very possible I've messed up some configuration by either using XAMPP or VirtualHostX.

Answer (score 0):

You also need to set the main document root in the http.conf file. Otherwise Apache will use the first vhost avaible.

Comment: It is set to the appropriate path: `DocumentRoot "/same/path/to/htdocs"`. Also the appropriate `<Directory>`-tag is edited properly.

Comment: Maybe post a (censored) version of your conf file.

Comment: What portions do you think would be most useful? The whole file is pretty long. I can copy the parts that would help.

Comment: Where you define the vhost and document root,

Answer (score 0):

You need to set up a localhost vhost. Once you enable virtual hosting, Apache uses the first vhost if no vhost match, as outlined in the documentation: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/en/vhosts/name-based.html.

Comment: I've tried using VirtualHostX to set a vhost like this: `localhost` -> `/path/to/htdocs`, but I get error 403 Forbidden. Here's an example of the lines that show up in logs (when requesting `localhost/foo`):
`[error] [client ::1] mod_hfs_apple: Mis-cased URI: /path/to/htdocs/foo, wants: /path/to/htdocs/`